# What is the difference between mlrun.code_to_function and mlrun.new_project?

Tags: nuclio, mlrun

What is the difference between `mlrun.code_to_function` and `mlrun.new_project`?
For example, we can deploy a function with `code_to_function`:

```
a_fn = mlrun.code_to_function(name='my_function', 
                              handler='handler', 
                              kind='nuclio', 
                              image='mlrun/mlrun')
a_fn.deploy()
```

or we can deploy a function with `mlrun.project.set_function`

```
project = mlrun.new_project(project_name_base,
                            context=project_path,                           
                            user_project=True)                                                    
fn = project.set_function("my_function.ipynb", 
                           name='my_function')
```

In which case I should use `code_to_function` or `set_function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the core concepts of MLRun is creating a serverless function out of a piece of code. You can specify a Python file, entrypoint function, Docker image, K8s resources, and more. `code_to_function` is how this is accomplished. See this page in the [docs](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/tutorial/01-mlrun-basics.html) for more info.

```py
# file.py
def handler(context):
    context.logger.info("Hello World")

# deploy.py
from mlrun import code_to_function, new_project

project = new_project(name="my-project")

fn = code_to_function(
    name="my-function",
    project="my-project",
    filename="file.py",
    kind="job",
    handler="handler",
    image="mlrun/mlrun"
)
fn.run()
```

You can create and run these functions on their own, or use something like KubeFlow to orchestrate a pipeline with multiple functions. `set_project` is part of that workflow. You can use the function created via `code_to_function` or just specify some of the parameters within `set_project`. Then, you will be able to use this function as a part of a larger KubeFlow pipeline. See this page in the [docs](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/tutorial/04-pipeline.html) for more info.

```py
project.set_function(fn)

project.set_function(
    name="my-function",
    func="file.py",
    kind="job",
    image="mlrun/mlrun"
)
```